# Functions defined by the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for classes of differentiable functions that are characterized by their second derivative.

For example:

- **convex functions:** function $f$ is convex iff its Hessian, $\nabla^2 f$, is positive semi-definite.
- **continuous submodular functions:** function $f$ is continuous submodular iff $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \leq 0$ for every $i \neq j$.

Are there any other function classes that can be characterized by their second derivative?

Comment: Not a very serious answer: Polynomials are functions which second derivatives are polynomials.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Yes, it looks better, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The harmonic functions are functions $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ which fulfill
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2 }+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2 }+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3^2 }+\cdots +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n^2 }=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

The affine functions are those functions $f$ for which every $\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ is equal to $0$.